# How can I have full control of the open state of InfoWindows in react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm trying to open and close `<InfoWindow>` components using a toggle of state. If `displayInfoWindow` is true, the component renders; if it is false, it doesn't.

Point.js

```
const Point = ({ point }) => {
  const [displayInfoWindow, setDisplayInfoWindow] = useState(false);

  const handlePointClick = () => {
    setDisplayInfoWindow(true);
  };

  return (
    <Marker
      onClick={handlePointClick}
      position={{ lat: point.coordinates.lat, lng: point.coordinates.lng }}
      key={point.key}
    >
      {displayInfoWindow && (
        <InfoWindow
          onCloseClick={() => setDisplayInfoWindow(!displayInfoWindow)}
        >
          <div className="Point">
            <h1>Info Window</h1>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </Marker>
  );
};
```

It's a fairly simple conditional rendering. The issue is when I want to also close the `<InfoWindow>` by clicking on anywhere else on the page. I added a hook to listen for these "outside" clicks that then closes the window.

useOnOutsideClick.js

```
const useOnOutsideClick = (refArray, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < refArray.length; i++) {
        const ref = refArray[i];
        if (
          !ref.current ||
          (ref.current.contains && ref.current.contains(e.target))
        ) {
          return;
        }
      }

      callback();
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    };
  }, [refArray, callback]);
};
```

Suddenly, the close functionality on the `<InfoWindow>`'s breaks. Most of the window will close but there is a bit of an ::after element that remains. (See the remaining white triangle in the image below)

[image]

Clearly the package is not designed to work like this, but I can't figure out how to close these by clicking outside of the window without the hook.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible with the `<InfoWindow>` component provided in the react-google-maps package. The issue was that I couldn't place the ref on the correct DOM element and part of the UI was left behind when the `displayInfoWindow` boolean was false.

In some more research, I've found that this component isn't very customizable. I've started using the `<OverlayView>` component instead.